# Installing Kvaser Drivers(Linuxcan) for RPI

Tags: pi-2, driver, can-bus

I have been attempting to install Kvaser drivers onto a RPI 2B and have been follwing the instructions listed in the following link:

https://www.kvaser.com/developer-blog/building-canlib-linuxcan-raspberry-pi/

However, when I get to the step in which I need to type in the "make" command, I get the following messages.

```
building kvcommon  Kernel src: /home/pi/linuxcan/linux-4153f509b449f1c1c816cf124c314975c3daa824 make
-C /home/pi/linuxcan/linux-4153f509b449f1c1c816cf124c314975c3daa824 SUBDIRS=/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common modules make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/linuxcan/linux-4153f509b449f1c1c816cf124c314975c3daa824'   CC [M]  /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/VCanOsIf.o   CC [M]  /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/objbuf.o   CC [M]  /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/osif_functions_kernel.o   CC [M]  /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/queue.o   CC [M]  /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.o In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/div64.h:126:0,
                 from ./include/linux/kernel.h:142,
                 from ./include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:53: /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c: In function ‘packed_EAN_to_BCD’: ./include/asm-generic/div64.h:207:28: error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]   (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0)); \
                            ^ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:87:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘do_div’
     c1 = do_div(ean64, 10);
          ^~~~~~ ./include/asm-generic/div64.h:207:28: error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]   (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0)); \
                            ^ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:88:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘do_div’
     c2 = do_div(ean64, 10);
          ^~~~~~ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c: In function ‘packed_EAN_to_BCD_with_csum’: ./include/asm-generic/div64.h:207:28: error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]   (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0)); \
                            ^ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:125:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘do_div’
     x = do_div(tmp, 10);
         ^~~~~~ ./include/asm-generic/div64.h:207:28: error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]   (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0)); \
                            ^ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:144:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘do_div’
     c1 = do_div(ean64, 10);
          ^~~~~~ ./include/asm-generic/div64.h:207:28: error: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [-Werror]   (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0)); \
                            ^ /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.c:145:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘do_div’
     c2 = do_div(ean64, 10);
          ^~~~~~ cc1: all warnings being treated as errors scripts/Makefile.build:293: recipe for target '/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.o' failed make[3]: *** [/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/util.o] Error 1 Makefile:1493: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common' failed make[2]: *** [_module_/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/linuxcan/linux-4153f509b449f1c1c816cf124c314975c3daa824' /home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common/../config.mak:135: recipe for target 'kv_module' failed make[1]: *** [kv_module] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/linuxcan/linuxcan/common' Makefile:94: recipe for target 'common' failed make: *** [common] Error 2
```

I have been trying to research into some of these error messages, but I wanted to know if someone already knew a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but rather a work-around:

Edit config.mak in linuxcan directory to remove the -Werror compiler flag.

try make again.  Watch for warnings.